# UnsupportedOperationException: Accumulate function (min) does not have reverseSupport

Tags: drools, optaplanner

I am using drools with optaplanner but when i start project sometimes it returns this exception and sometimes didn't return any exception with same code.

THE RULE:

```
rule "groupedSteps"
when
            $Act : Action(this !=null,Step != null,$step : getStepType().getId(),isCanItBeGrouped(),period !=null)
              accumulate(
                  Action(this != null,Step != null,period != null,isCanItBeGrouped(),getStepType().getId() == $step,$startTime : getStartTime(),getStartTime() >= 0);
                  $firstStart : min(checkStartTimeIsBigOrEqualToZero($startTime))
                  )

    Action($firstStart == getStartTime(),$step == getStepType().getId(),isCanItBeGrouped() == true,$xMachine : Machine, $employee : Employee,period != null)
    Action(this != null,isCanItBeGrouped() == true,getStepType().getId() == $step,$xStartTime : getStartTime(),$xMach : Machine,$xEmployee : Employee,period != null,Employee !=null)
    eval($xStartTime < (int)$firstStart || $xEmployee != $employee || $xMachine != $xMach)
then
scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -5);
end
```

THE checkStartTimeIsBigOrEqualToZero METHOD:

```
function int checkStartTimeIsBigOrEqualToZero(int startTime)
{
   try{
       if (startTime >= 0)
           return startTime;
       else
           return 99999;
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           return 99999;
       }
}
```

FULL ERROR:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" Exception executing consequence
>   for rule "groupedSteps" in org.optaplanner.examples.opnext.solver:
>   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Accumulate function (min)
>   used in rule(s) [groupedSteps] does not have reverseSupport   at
>   org.drools.core.runtime.rule.impl.DefaultConsequenceExceptionHandler.handleException(DefaultConsequenceExceptionHandler.java:39)
>     at
>   org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda.handleException(DefaultAgenda.java:1247)
>     at
>   org.drools.core.phreak.RuleExecutor.innerFireActivation(RuleExecutor.java:438)
>     at
>   org.drools.core.phreak.RuleExecutor.fireActivation(RuleExecutor.java:379)
>     at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleExecutor.fire(RuleExecutor.java:135)
>     at
>   org.drools.core.phreak.RuleExecutor.evaluateNetworkAndFire(RuleExecutor.java:88)
>     at
>   org.drools.core.concurrent.AbstractRuleEvaluator.internalEvaluateAndFire(AbstractRuleEvaluator.java:34)
>     at
>   org.drools.core.concurrent.SequentialRuleEvaluator.evaluateAndFire(SequentialRuleEvaluator.java:43)
>     at
>   org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda.fireLoop(DefaultAgenda.java:1067)
>     at
>   org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda.internalFireAllRules(DefaultAgenda.java:1014)
>     at
>   org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda.fireAllRules(DefaultAgenda.java:1006)
>     at
>   org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.internalFireAllRules(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:1318)
>     at
>   org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.fireAllRules(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:1309)
>     at
>   org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.fireAllRules(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:1293)
>     at
>   org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.drools.DroolsScoreDirector.calculateScore(DroolsScoreDirector.java:117)
>     at
>   org.optaplanner.examples.common.business.SolutionBusiness.getScore(SolutionBusiness.java:218)
>     at
>   org.optaplanner.examples.opnext.business.CalculatorClass.bestSolutionChanged(CalculatorClass.java:149)
>     at
>   org.optaplanner.examples.common.business.SolutionBusiness.lambda$null$0(SolutionBusiness.java:247)
>     at
>   java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch$$$capture(InvocationEvent.java:311)
>     at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
>   Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Accumulate
>   function (min) used in rule(s) [groupedSteps] does not have
>   reverseSupport    at
>   org.drools.core.reteoo.FromNodeLeftTuple.getAccumulatedObjects(FromNodeLeftTuple.java:105)
>     at
>   org.drools.core.common.AgendaItem.getObjectsDeep(AgendaItem.java:79)
>     at
>   org.drools.core.reteoo.RuleTerminalNodeLeftTuple.getObjectsDeep(RuleTerminalNodeLeftTuple.java:359)
>     at
>   org.optaplanner.core.api.score.holder.AbstractScoreHolder.extractJustificationList(AbstractScoreHolder.java:118)
>     at
>   org.optaplanner.core.api.score.holder.AbstractScoreHolder.registerConstraintMatch(AbstractScoreHolder.java:88)
>     at
>   org.optaplanner.core.api.score.buildin.hardmediumsoft.HardMediumSoftScoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(HardMediumSoftScoreHolder.java:58)
>     at
>   org.optaplanner.examples.opnext.solver.Rule_groupedSteps547703499.defaultConsequence(Rule_groupedSteps547703499.java:21)
>     at
>   org.optaplanner.examples.opnext.solver.Rule_groupedSteps547703499DefaultConsequenceInvokerGenerated.evaluate(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.optaplanner.examples.opnext.solver.Rule_groupedSteps547703499DefaultConsequenceInvoker.evaluate(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.drools.core.phreak.RuleExecutor.innerFireActivation(RuleExecutor.java:431)
>     ... 30 more

Comment: Sometimes it does and sometimes it doesn't? OptaPlanner-Drools should be fully reproducible. If you run the same dataset twice with the same number of stepLimit in optaplanner, you should get the same error at the same step iteration.

Comment: And which version do your drools-core.jar and optaplanner-core.jar have?

Comment: this error return from bestsolutionchanged method.
drools-core : 7.6.0 snapshot and optaplanner is lastest version from github.i changed it

Comment: Score score = solutionBusiness.getScore(); this code returns this exception but i covered it with a while and i recalculated when it fail and it return the score without exception after try 2 or 3 round.

Comment: Can you submit a jira with a reproducer? See optaplanner.org -> get help which has a link to our jira.

Comment: of course i am openning now.

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet could I know the jira link for this issue?

Comment: I don't know. @KadirKalkan what's the jira issue url?